# Getting error 409 "confict" because of Task.WhenAll() involving SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, task-parallel-library

I'm asking this more because I have no idea of why the way I solved the issue works.

Here's the method that gives me the error (notice the return line):

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<ContractServiceResponse>> GetContractServices(Guid contractId)
{
    var services = await _translationManager.GetCachedResource<Service>();

    var rates = await _translationManager.GetCachedResource<Rate>();

    var contractServices = await _dbContext.ContractService
       .Where(cs => cs.ContractId == contractId)
       .ToListAsync();

    var serviceCenterBillableConcepts = await _billableConceptService.GetServiceCenterBillableConcepts(services.Select(s => s.Id).Distinct());

    var contractBillableConcepts = await _billableConceptService.GetContractBillableConcepts(contractId);

    var servicesResponse = contractServices.Select(async cs => new ContractServiceResponse
    {
        Id = cs.ServiceId,
        Service = services.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == cs.ServiceId).Translation,
        Enabled = cs.Billable,
        ExceptionReason = cs.BillableExceptionReason,
        BillableConcepts = await AddContractBillableConceptsToServices(cs.ServiceId, contractBillableConcepts, serviceCenterBillableConcepts, rates)
    });

    return await Task.WhenAll(servicesResponse);
}
```

And here's the code that works (notice the return line).

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<ContractServiceResponse>> GetContractServices(Guid contractId)
{
    var services = await _translationManager.GetCachedResource<Service>();

    var rates = await _translationManager.GetCachedResource<Rate>();

    var contractServices = await _dbContext.ContractService
       .Where(cs => cs.ContractId == contractId)
       .ToListAsync();

    var serviceCenterBillableConcepts = await _billableConceptService.GetServiceCenterBillableConcepts(services.Select(s => s.Id).Distinct());

    var contractBillableConcepts = await _billableConceptService.GetContractBillableConcepts(contractId);

    var servicesResponse = contractServices.Select(async cs => new ContractServiceResponse
    {
        Id = cs.ServiceId,
        Service = services.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == cs.ServiceId).Translation,
        Enabled = cs.Billable,
        ExceptionReason = cs.BillableExceptionReason,
        BillableConcepts = await AddContractBillableConceptsToServices(cs.ServiceId, contractBillableConcepts, serviceCenterBillableConcepts, rates)
    });

    return servicesResponse.Select(t => t.Result);
}
```

Why the second one works, but the first one doesn't?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As I side note, I would suggest to change the return type from `Task<IEnumerable<ContractServiceResponse>>` to `Task<IList<ContractServiceResponse>>` or `Task<ContractServiceResponse[]>`. The `IEnumerable<T>` carries strong deferred semantics, the `Task<T>` has promise semantics, and the combination of both semantics can be confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this has nothing to do with SqlDataReader or any database. Databases don't return HTTP status codes. The 409 is returned by whatever is called by `await AddContractBillableConceptsToServices`

The first example executes as many calls as there are items in `contractServices` *at the exact same time*. If there are 100 items, it will execute 100 requests. All those requests would try to allocate and use memory, access databases or limited other resources at the same time, causing blocks, queueing and possibly deadlocks. Making 100 concurrent calls could easily result in 100x degradation if not outright crashing the service.

That's why production services always implement throttling and queuing, and, if a client is ill-behaved, will throw a 409 and block it for a while.

The second code runs sequentially. `t.Result` *blocks* until the task `t` completes, so the second code is no different than:

```
foreach(var cs in contractServices)
{
    var t=AddContractBillableConceptsToServices(cs.ServiceId, contractBillableConcepts, serviceCenterBillableConcepts, rates);
    t.Wait();
    yield return  new ContractServiceResponse
    {
        BillableConcepts = t.Result
    }
}
```

**Execute only N requests at a time**

A real solution is to execute only a limited number of requests at a time, using, eg `Parallel.ForEachAsync` :

```
var results=new ConcurrentQueue<ContractServiceResponse> ();
Parallel.ForEachAsync(contractServices, async cs=>{
    var concepts=AddContractBillableConceptsToServices(cs.ServiceId, contractBillableConcepts, serviceCenterBillableConcepts, rates);
    var response=new ContractServiceResponse
    {
        ...
        BillableConcepts = concepts
    }
    results.Enqueue(response);    
});
```

By default, [ForEachAsync](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/parallelforeachasync-in-net-6) will make as many concurrent calls as there are cores. This can be changed through the `ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism` property.

Answer (score 1):

Youre executing everything in sequence. servicesResponse.Select(t => t.Result) won't do anything until the IEnumerable is enumerated by the consumer.

Task.WhenAll() will run the tasks in parallel. Your issue is that the code you're calling, does not play nice with parallelism.

To solve this, don't use WhenAll, but just use await.
Alternatively you can pinpoint the code which breaks when it is run in parallel, and implement some kind of locking mechanism using a `semaphoreslim`